# Ruby rescue TypeError is not catching TypeError exception

Tags: ruby, typeerror, rescue

I'm using a Gem called bindata which has the following code block:

```
def assign(val)
  raise ArgumentError, "can't set a nil value for #{debug_name}" if val.nil?

  unless has_parameter?(:value)
    raw_val = val.respond_to?(:snapshot) ? val.snapshot : val
    @value = begin
               raw_val.dup
             rescue TypeError
               # can't dup Fixnums
               raw_val
             end
  end
end
```

This code is meant to dup the object sent to the assign function, but a Fixnum cannot be dup'd so the creators put the rescue block in there.  I have tested this code multiple times in Rails Console and the rescue works fine.  However:

```
I, [2017-04-08T00:03:47.165387 #27899]  INFO -- : *** below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally ***
E, [2017-04-08T00:03:47.165450 #27899] ERROR -- : can't dup Fixnum (TypeError)
/home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/gems/bindata-1.4.3/lib/bindata/base_primitive.rb:90:in `dup'
/home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/gems/bindata-1.4.3/lib/bindata/base_primitive.rb:90:in `assign'
(eval):3:in `assign'
```

It seems like this code is working in catching the error %99.99 of the time, but every once in a while it crashes instead.  Any idea why the rescue would randomly fail?  My code is splattered with calls to the Bindata gem, so putting a rescue surrounding every call would be a tedious effort.

Thanks!

Comment: No idea, but I would recommend upgrading `bindata` and Ruby. Might solve the problem.

Comment: I looked into updating the Gem to the latest version, but the code block in question hasn't changed so I questioned whether upgrading it would help.  We are also pretty locked to Ruby 1.9.3 at the moment, but are considering upgrading it as well.